# how to use mqtt.Client(streamBuilder, options) constructor in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I'm trying to build simple MQTT application using npm package "mqtt.js". I've tried mqtt.connect() constructor and it works fine but I want to explore more features of MQTT hence I want to use mqtt.client() constructor. The official documentation has no example so I'm confused.
here's what I have tried so far
var mqtt = require('mqtt')

client1:-

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')

client = mqtt.connect('http://localhost:1883',{clientId :'client1', clean: false});

  client.on('connect', function () {
    client.subscribe('presence',{QoS:2});
    client.subscribe('offline',{QoS:2});
    console.log('connected');
  });
  client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    console.log(message.toString());
  });
```

client2:-

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')

client = mqtt.connect('http://localhost:1883',{clientId :'client2', clean: false,will:{topic:'offline',payload:'off',qos:2}});

   client.on('connect', function () {
    client.publish('presence', '{message:hello,id:1}',{QoS:2});

  });
```

any example would be helpful.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass client connection options directly in the connect() call, as in the following snippet:

```
// Connect with unique clientId and set clean to false, so as to receive any
// missed QOS 1 or 2 messages received at broker when this worker was down.
this.MqttClient = mqtt.connect(this.tls_url,{clientId : this.myClientId, clean: false});

this.MqttClient.on('connect', function(connack){
    // do stufff       
});
```

Comment: thanks.. I've set qos still not receiving any messages if client is down .here's my subscribe publish code --> client.subscribe('presence',{QoS:2});  client.publish('presence', '{message:hello,id:1}',{QoS:2});

Comment: Is your client connecting, i.e. are you handling the 'connect' event, and is your handler getting called?

Comment: yes.it is connecting and i'm getting messages as long as client is online.But if I stop the client and publish and again restart the client nothing happens. BTW i'm using mosquitto locally.

Comment: If you want to receive QOS 1 and 2 messages that were published while your client was offline, you need to connect with an unique clientId and set 'clean' to false, like in the above snippet I posted.

Comment: i've updated my question with my program please take a look

Comment: Try {qos : 2} instead of {QoS : 2}

Comment: no luck..but client receives "offline" topic but not "presence". I tried removing "offline" topic.. still no luck.